# Google Analytic [[GANTracker sharedTracker] stopTracker];

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Right now i am using Google Analytic in my Ipad application for tracking pageview and events i have implemented below code for all my viewController and button click event but when my view disappear my application stop/crash.I have putted stopTracker code `[[GANTracker sharedTracker] stopTracker];` in viewWillDisappear method.

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] startTrackerWithAccountID:@"UA-12345678-1"
                                       dispatchPeriod:kGANDispatchPeriodSec
                                             delegate:nil];

NSError *error;
if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1
                                                     name:@"iPad3"
                                                    value:@"iv1"
                                                withError:&error]) {
    // Handle error here
}

if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"my_category"
                                     action:@"my_action"
                                      label:@"my_label"
                                      value:-1
                                  withError:&error]) {
    // Handle error here
}

if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview:@"/app_entry_point_prashant"
                                     withError:&error]) {
    // Handle error here
}
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] stopTracker];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the call to stopTracker to the dealloc method of your AppDelegate. Make it the first line within that method.

You should only call stopTracker once and that should be in the place I mention above. You should also move the initialisation of the shared tracker out of your viewControllers and into the appDelegate's appDidFinishLaunching method, again this should happen only once.

There should only be one shared tracker initialised at app launch and eventually 'stopped' when the app terminates.